# send an undefined soap header in C#

Tags: .net, wsdl, webservice-client, soapheader

I have a web service implemented in java and appache axis.I want to call that service in .Net.
the problem is there is a required soap header but it is not defined in the wsdl !!

the soap header must be look like this :

`<soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:sessionID soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="urn:handlers.ws">778846user</ns1:sessionID> 
  </soapenv:Header>`

Is there any way to send this header using .NET ??

Answer (score 0):

If you add the webservice as a reference to the project you can call the service methods with C#/VB. 
The .net framework will build your SOAP message, including the SOAP header.